# How to show data from database using for loop in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter, for-loop, codeigniter-3

I have a project called Loan Application using CodeIgniter 3. I cant solve this problem, this is for my payment list of a certain borrowers. I wanted to show his/her payment details everyday transactions.

I wanted to show this on my views.
This is my table in database:
[image]

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `payment_transactions` WHERE loan_no = '$data' ORDER BY payment_no LIMIT 0,29"
```

I have a problem showing this on my view.
I dont know what is the problem but It only shows 2 data in my database.

[image]

I cant figure out what is my problem about this.

This is my code in my views:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=29 ; $i++) {?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i+1;?></td>
       <?php 
           $a = $i+1;
           if(!empty($first_mnth[$i]['payment_no'])){
              $p = $first_mnth[$i]['payment_no'];
           }
           if(!empty($first_mnth[$i]['date'])){
              $d = $first_mnth[$i]['date']; 
           }
           if(!empty($first_mnth[$i]['amount'])){
              $am = $first_mnth[$i]['amount']; 
           }
           if(!empty($first_mnth[$i]['notes'])){
              $n = $first_mnth[$i]['notes']; 
           }
       ?>
       <td>
          <?php 
            if($a != $p){
              continue;
            }
            echo $p;
          ?>    
       </td>
       <td>
         <?php 
            if($a != $p){
              continue;
            }
            echo 'P '.$am;
         ?>
       </td>
       <td>
          <?php 
            if($a != $p){
               continue;
            }
            echo $n;
          ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

My goal is to show all the payment details of a certain borrower within 30 days. That's
why I have payment_no in my database for my query and also it indicates what no. days he/she pays. I wanted to skip the table in my views if he/she did not pay in that day.

But I cant solve the problem. Hope someone can help me about this and cite what is the problem of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition & your other if condition before starting "tr" tag

```
<?php if($a != $p){ continue; } ?>
```